# How to get the most representative image of a webpage?

Tags: html, parsing, web-crawler

There are some cases when you want to get a most representative image
of a web page, e.g. Pocket would try to add an image when you collect
a web page.

How would you define, in a programmatic way, which image is the key
image?
What would be the most appropriate way to do so?

Answer (score 4):

Most websites that are seeking to be shared on sites like Facebook or Pocket will have an [Open Graph protocol](http://ogp.me/) image. This is often an image in the `head` tag that uses the format `<meta property="og:image" content="http://URL-TO-YOUR-IMAGE" />`. The Open Graph protocol is used and looked for by companies such as Facebook, Pocket, Reddit, and has become fairly widespread in use.

For websites that do *not* follow such a standard, developers will often use a third-party tool such as [Embedly](http://embed.ly/), which has already solved the problem. Simply feed it a URL and it will return you some information on what content would be good for your thumbnail-ified images.

If you're wanting to create your own engine, you may want to study into DOM positioning analytics, and try to find your own algorithm by scraping many, many articles and web pages to try and find good patterns.

Comment: Do you have any idea how tools like Embedly decide which image is most appropriate to use? Is there any open-source tool that can do similar things?

Answer (score 2):

Study [scraper.py](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/blob/a6a4da72a1a0f44e0174b2ad0a865b9f68d3c1cd/r2/r2/lib/scraper.py) to see how reddit uses [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to find representative images from links submitted to it.